# How do I search a string for keywords in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I search $html for these exact words "$2.99 Buy", and return a positive when found? It would also help if it was case sensitive.

My goal is to check iTunes and see if the current selected book is still $2.99

```
<?php $html = file_get_contents ($urlonitunes);

echo $html;?>
```

Comment: either you are a total beginner(which I doubt) or you have put 0% research in your question, cause this is easily to find everywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: You'll may find that there is various whitespace types (spaces, tabs, carriage returns) between the price and the word 'Buy'), so you may find a regular expression useful here - even though they are generally not recommended for use on HTML.

Comment: I have been experimenting with strpos for some time, but it doesn't seem to work on a continuous line of html like finding ">$2.99<" in this line:its.detect.openItunes(&#39;https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-13th-tribe/id614748729?mt=11&#39;);" href="#" class="action view-in-itunes"><span>View In iTunes</span></a> <ul class="list"><li><div class="price">$2.99</div></li><li><span class="availability-message">Available on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.</span></li><li class="genre"><span

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if(strpos($html, '$2.99 Buy') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'found';
}
```